# app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED when building Andriod in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I had created my react Native project and converted it to work with Expo for development. 
At this stage, I have ejected back the project to react native and everything seems to be correct.

When I run the command `sudo react-native run-android`

I get the following error

> app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Could not create an instance of type com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.

I have googled for hours now and I can not still get a solution to this issue.

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04

Any help on this issue will be highly welcomed